# Multiple Conditions in Nhibernate Left Join

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Please need some help converting this sql query to nhibernate

```
select     a.ID, count(b.ID)
from       appusers    a
left join  weeklytasks b on a.ID = b.TaskOwner and b.taskstatus = 1
group by   a.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without knowing your entities, mappings, used technology(ICreteria API, QueryOver, Linq).

But I can suggest this solution using QueryOver:

```
AppUser ownerAlias = null;
WeeklyTask taskAlias = null;
var result = Session.QueryOver(() => taskAlias)
                .JoinAlias(x => x.TaskOwner, 
                           () => ownerAlias,
                           NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.RightOuterJoin,
                           Restrictions.Where(() => taskAlias.Status == 1))
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectGroup(x => ownerAlias.Id)
                    .SelectCount(x => x.Id))
                .List<object[]>();
```

or this:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<WeeklyTask>()
                .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
                .Right.JoinQueryOver(x => x.TaskOwner)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectGroup(x => x.TaskOwner.Id)
                    .SelectCount(x => x.Id))
                .List<object[]>();
```

Please notice that in this approach your `WeeklyTask` entity must contains mapped reference to `AppUser` entity.